# Не работает USB2.0

Tags: usb

У меня на компьютере:

- *Мать*: MS-7525
- *Проц*: core 2 duo intel
- *Память*: 2гига кингстон
- *ЖД*: 320Гб

В общем - это белая сборка от HP NA106PA. Не работает концентратор USB 2.0.
Когда отключаю концентратор USB 2.0 в диспетчере задач, срабатывает просто USB на низкой скорости. Когда включаю, перестает видеть флешку и другие устройства.

В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 1):

Может питание не хватает. Так же в биосе поиграться настройкой, что то типа "Legacy USB"...

Comment: В биосе нет такого пункта. Долго искал. Питание: переключал джампер с 3 вольт на 5 и обратно, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: В общем единственный подобный конкретный случай, который у меня был в практике, закончился тем что купили другой концентратор и все заработало)

Comment: Ага,я купил два концентратора один USB2.0 на слот PCI. И другой USB3.0 на слот PCI-X 1x... Сейчас все работает на ура. А штатные рабтаю на USB1.0...Таким образом у меня теперь все версии USB... ахаха